# Analyzing Git repository with SonarQube from Jenkins Pipeline with Docker Container Sonar Scanner throws error - could not get uid/gid

Tags: git, docker, jenkins, sonarqube

I'm trying to analyze a git repository within Jenkins pipeline while using Sonar Scanner from docker container. My jenkins pipeline code looks like this:

```
pipeline {
    agent { 
        docker {
        image 'node:lts-alpine' 
        args  '-u root:root' 
            }
        }
    stages {
        stage('build && SonarQube analysis') {
            steps {
                sh 'npm install -g sonarqube-scanner'
                withSonarQubeEnv('sonar.tools.devops.***') {
                    sh 'sonar-scanner -Dsonar.projectKey=**** -Dsonar.sources=./src'
                }
            }
        }
        stage("Quality Gate") {
            steps {
                timeout(time: 1, unit: 'HOURS') {
                    // Parameter indicates whether to set pipeline to UNSTABLE if Quality Gate fails
                    // true = set pipeline to UNSTABLE, false = don't
                    // Requires SonarScanner for Jenkins 2.7+
                    waitForQualityGate abortPipeline: true
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The analysis fails on part  sh 'npm install -g sonarqube-scanner'

with this error:

```
 + npm install -g sonarqube-scanner
Error: could not get uid/gid
[ 'nobody', 0 ]

    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/uid-number/uid-number.js:37:16
    at ChildProcess.exithandler (child_process.js:301:5)
    at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:198:13)
    at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:982:16)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:259:5)
TypeError: Cannot read property 'loaded' of undefined
    at exit (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/utils/error-handler.js:98:27)
    at errorHandler (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/utils/error-handler.js:216:3)
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/bin/npm-cli.js:77:20
    at cb (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/npm.js:225:22)
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/npm.js:263:24
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/config/core.js:83:7
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/config/core.js:82:13
    at f (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/once/once.js:25:25)
    at afterExtras (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/config/core.js:173:20)
/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/utils/error-handler.js:98
  var doExit = npm.config.loaded ? npm.config.get('_exit') : true
                          ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'loaded' of undefined
    at exit (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/utils/error-handler.js:98:27)
    at process.errorHandler (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/utils/error-handler.js:216:3)
    at process.emit (events.js:198:13)
    at process._fatalException (internal/bootstrap/node.js:496:27)
```

I'm running nodejs because I need to analyze typescript project within SonarQube.